# Do i require a licence for Angular 2 kendo UI components.

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am currently using below list of kendo grid components in my angular 4 application. Do i need any licence in future. Can you any one please let me know if below things are opensource or not.

npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-grid @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns @progress/kendo-angular-inputs @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs @progress/kendo-data-query @progress/kendo-angular-intl @progress/kendo-angular-l10n @progress/kendo-drawing @progress/kendo-angular-excel-export @angular/animations

Comment: Hm, I also wonder how that works. Its clearly stated on their site that UI for Angular is for sale, so they definitely want to get money if you use it.  But if they let you download it without any purchase verification I assume they use some links to inform them if someone is using it. SO wonder what will happen if you install those components without paying? They will contact you by email in Whois database? What if its a private domain registration? What if I am a student and installation guide was provided by my friend so I was not aware of that it cost money? Could anyone reply on this?

Comment: I have just sen this to the Kendo support. Hope they will answer